# How to get latest N entries from two tables in a database?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask

***I am trying to make a project using flask to track the expense of the users.***

And I have two tables in a database .. Income and Expense
Income table has **user_id,income,datetime_utc** as columns
and 
Expense table has **user_id,expense_amt,description,datetime_utc** as columns.

And I wanna show the users latest N=10 transaction with the web app i.e his/her last 10 expense and income amount added to the database.

For that i have to compare the datetime_utc column of two tables to find out which one are the latest N entries

And i dont seem to find the logic for doing that :(
Any help for this logic??
Note:I am using orm flask_sqlalchemy but sql answer will be appreciated

Comment: The question is not clear, so voting to close. Tables do not match in columns, and there's no expected result to perform an educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they have the same data structure, then:

```
select ie.*
from ((select i.* 
       from income i
       where user_id = ?
       order by i.datetime_utc desc
       limit 10
      ) union all
      (select e.* 
       from expense e
       where e.user_id = ?
       order by e.datetime_utc desc
       limit 10
      )
     ) ie
order by datetime_utc desc
limit 10;
```

The inner query selects the 10 most recents income and expense transactions for the given user.  The outer query then chooses 10 amongst these.

Comment: Both tables dont have same number of columns so do you think union all will work in that???

Comment: @BinitDhakal . . . No, it would not work.  You would then need to explicitly list the columns in each table that you want.

Comment: I guess i have to make the number of column same thank you for your guidance @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the latest 10 transactions from *both* tables. As @TheImpaler noted both union subqueries are limited to 10 entries for the worst case when all result entries would come from the same table.

```sql
with t (user_id, amount, datetime_utc, transaction_type) as 
(
 select user_id, income, datetime_utc, 'income'::text from income
   where user_id = $1 order by datetime_utc desc limit 10
 union
 select user_id, expense_amt, datetime_utc, 'expense' from expense
   where user_id = $1 order by datetime_utc desc limit 10
) 
select * from t order by datetime_utc desc limit 10;
```